# How to catch physical keyboard input and in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

```
private void send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (Application.Current as App).Broadcast(new ChatMessage { Username = name.Text, Message = text.Text });
    text.Text = "";
}
```

This is my click event but I'm tired of moving my cursor to click it. 
Is there any way to set the enter button to active this event?

Comment: Which GUI Framework are you using? WPF, Winforms?

Comment: Iam using UWP platform

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950918/keydown-handling-c-sharp-uwp ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792978/page-global-keyboard-events-in-windows-store-apps
no idea if this is still valid in uwp but worth taking a look

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar, not sure you can use jquery in UWP

Comment: I dont know how to write it down in my case

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the key bindings in the xaml file as follows:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding EnterKeyPressCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

EnterKeyPressCommand: This can be a DelegateCommand in the code behind or view model whatever is the DataContext of your view.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a KeyDown event in your textbox and fire your send_Click event if 'Enter' is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Just capture the [`KeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_KeyDown) event handle for the container you want to capture the input for, and then to judge if the input [virtual key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.virtualkey) is `Enter`. For example, the following demo capture the keyboard inputs for `CoreWindow`.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
}

private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
{           
    if (args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(args.VirtualKey.ToString());
        //(Application.Current as App).Broadcast(new ChatMessage { Username = name.Text, Message = text.Text });
        //text.Text = "";
    }
}
```

More details please reference [Keyboard events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-events).